# Is there a way to quickly wake up all units of one type?

Tags: civilization-4

Let's say I have some swordsmen scattered about my kingdom, and I want to bring them all up to one point to take an enemy city. What's the fastest way to do this?

I'm aware of th emilitary advisor screen, but I can only figure out how to see their location on the map - not very useful. In Civ III I seem to remember a way to "Wake All" units of a specific type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe theres a way to order unit movement for units on different tiles at the same time.

To wake up all units of one type, you can use the `ALT` key modifier when *clicking* the wake button (the shortcut `ALT+F` will not work, as it is bound to another function).

[image: Wake All]